# SonarQube at unix don't see java class (issue does not exist at windows)

Tags: java, linux, windows, development-environment, sonarqube

I had a SonarQube configured at RedHat with Jenkins (and Sonar plugins for Jenkins).

Developers work at various machines (linux, windows, mac) at one project I have a problem with I'm struggling for couple of days and I don't have any idea where the problem lay.

Namely, the point is that during Sonar analyse I get the following error:

```
[INFO] [03:49:52.870] Java AST scan...
[ERROR] [03:49:54.755] [main] ERROR IOException java.io.IOException: No such file or directory while creating temporary volume 
[ERROR] [03:49:54.789] [PAGE_WRITER:8192] ERROR IOException java.io.IOException: No such file or directory while creating temporary volume 
[ERROR] [03:49:54.790] [PAGE_WRITER:8192] ERROR com.persistit.exception.PersistitIOException: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
```

The root cause is following:

```
Caused by: org.sonar.squid.api.AnalysisException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : '/home/resbuild/jenkins_working/jobs/Project_JavaSonar/workspace/src/main/java/com/company/dto/AnalysisDTO.java'
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
```

I tried to execute analyse at local environment at windows and my analyse gone without any problem. Problem exist only at linux environments. I check the following path and linux and path and file exist (I check case-sensitive too).

What I missing ?

Comment: Is that file readable/executable by the user that Sonar runs as?

Comment: Yes, file is readable/executable by the user that Sonar runs as.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you solve it?

Comment: Hi, as I remember the problem has not been fixed.  Currently I'm working on different company so I don't know how the situation was resolved.